# Poppler is installed, pdf2image path error seems to have no resolution. Has this been fixed?

Tags: python-3.x, poppler, debian-buster, pdf2image

I am running debian buster on the docker image. I have installed every poppler package to rule anything unusual out. I have explicitly added the paths to all of the poppler files, containing directories, etc.

I have followed the documentation available on the `pdf2image` website here: https://pdf2image.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#

And have confirmed that poppler is installed and on the path with the recommended method:

```
root@1018c6c180a9:/# pdftoppm -h
pdftoppm version 0.71.0
Copyright 2005-2018 The Poppler Developers - http://poppler.freedesktop.org
Copyright 1996-2011 Glyph & Cog, LLC
Usage: pdftoppm [options] [PDF-file [PPM-file-prefix]]
  -f <int>                 : first page to print
  -l <int>                 : last page to print
  -o                       : print only odd pages
  -e                       : print only even pages
...
```

And I get the following error when running in a docker image:

```
pdf2image.exceptions.PDFInfoNotInstalledError: Unable to get page count. Is poppler installed and in PATH?
```

I still assume I have made the mistake.  But, it seems like the results that pop up on a search indicate that this is somewhat unresolved, with working scenarios achieved for some, but not all, users of the poppler library and python package `pdf2image`.

I don't have constraints on the debian image I use, or the pdf2image version, per say.

Is there a working configuration out there, is this issue resolved, or is there a hot spot for mistakes where everyone seems to have a similar problem (and I have fallen into the same trap)?

*python3 vers 3.8*

Comment: Did you find a solution for this, Chris?

Comment: @xssChauhan no - I wound up bypassing this dependency with ghostscript (`libgs`)